# Repeat the job without repeat typing the script for each value

Tags: autoit

I have this Autoit script working good but how I can make it repeat the job without repeat typing the script for each value ?

Value1 = usernameA work with passwordA

Value2 = usernameB work with passwordB

Value3 = usernameC work with passwordB

```
#include <IE.au3>
$oIE = _IECreate ("www.site.com/login")

$username = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_username")
$id = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_username")
$password = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_password")
$id = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_password")
$button1 =  _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "login")

_IEPropertySet($username, 'innerText', 'usernameA')
_IEPropertySet($id, 'innerText', 'usernameA')
_IEPropertySet($Password, 'innerText', 'passwordA')
_IEPropertySet($id, 'innerText', 'passwordA')
_IEAction ($button1,"click")
```

I do not want it to be like this !

```
#include <IE.au3>

$oIE = _IECreate ("www.site.com/login")
$username = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_username")
$id = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_username")
$password = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_password")
$id = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_password")
$button1 =  _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "login")

_IEPropertySet($username, 'innerText', 'usernamea')
_IEPropertySet($id, 'innerText', 'usernameA')
_IEPropertySet($Password, 'innerText', 'passworA')
_IEPropertySet($id, 'innerText', 'passwordA')
_IEAction ($button1,"click")

$oIE = _IECreate ("www.site.com/login")
$username = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_username")
$id = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_username")
$password = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_password")
$id = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_password")
$button1 =  _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "login")

_IEPropertySet($username, 'innerText', 'usernameB')
_IEPropertySet($id, 'innerText', 'usernameB')
_IEPropertySet($Password, 'innerText', 'passwordB')
_IEPropertySet($id, 'innerText', 'passwordB')
_IEAction ($button1,"click")

$oIE = _IECreate ("www.site.com/login")
$username = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_username")
$id = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "j_username")
$password = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_password")
$id = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_password")
$button1 =  _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "login")

_IEPropertySet($username, 'innerText', 'usernameC')
_IEPropertySet($id, 'innerText', 'usernameC')
_IEPropertySet($Password, 'innerText', 'passwordC')
_IEPropertySet($id, 'innerText', 'passwordC')
_IEAction ($button1,"click")
```

Also how make it  go back to first  line on the script when it finish ?

Comment: You don't need to `#include <IE.au3>` several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Function:

```
#include <IE.au3>

Func TestPassword($user, $pass)
    $oIE = _IECreate ("www.site.com/login")

    $username = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_username")
    $id = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_username")
    $password = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_password")
    $id = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "q_password")
    $button1 =  _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "login")

    _IEPropertySet($username, 'innerText', $user)
    _IEPropertySet($id, 'innerText', $user)
    _IEPropertySet($Password, 'innerText', $pass)
    _IEPropertySet($id, 'innerText', $pass)

    _IEAction ($button1,"click")
EndFunc


TestPassword('usernameA', 'passwordA');
TestPassword('usernameB', 'passwordB');
TestPassword('usernameC', 'passwordC');
```

You can even make an array and iterate through it with `For...In...`:

```
$credentials[0]['user'] = 'usernameA';
$credentials[0]['pass'] = 'passwordA';
$credentials[1]['user'] = 'usernameB';
$credentials[1]['pass'] = 'passwordB';

For $cred In $credentials
    TestPassword($cred['user'], $cred['pass']);
Next
```